# loading image not showing jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a file upload button which uploads file via ajax and I am displaying the uploaded picture back by sending ajax request every 3 seconds, The problem is that, I would like to show a loading image whenever the user clicks upload button and hide it on success, but the image is not showing. As said above I have another ajax call to fetch for the uploaded picture   and I think it is hiding the picture. So what I want simply is, when the user click on the button show the loading image then when the 2nd ajax call displays the uploaded image back to the user, hide the image. can someone give me hint?

```
$("#loading_image").html('<div class="loadm"><img src="../image/ajax-loader.gif"/>//I have tried putting the loading image on the also.

$(document).ready(function()
{
     profileRefresh();
    var uploaded_files_location = "../img/";
    new AjaxUpload($('#upload_button '), 
    {   
        hoverClass: 'btn - primary',
        action: 'picture.php ? target = profile ',
        name: 'file_to_upload ',
        onSubmit: function(file, file_extensions){
            $('#errormsg ').html('');

            if (!(file_extensions && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|JPG)$/.test(file_extensions)))
            {
                $('#error ').html(' < div class = "error" align = "left" > Sorry, you can only upload the following file formats : JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF... < /div>');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#loading_image").html('<div class="loadm"><img src="../image / ajax - loader.gif "/></div>');//this is the loading image that is not showing.
                return true;
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){}
    });
});


var profileRefresh = function() {
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET ",
        url: "picture ? target = refresh ",  
        success: function(response){ 
            $("#pro").html(response);
             setTimeout(profileRefresh, 3000); 
            $("#loading_image ").fadeOut('fast');// hide the loading image
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: do you want to set or get the image?

Comment: @Soombinakundi simply until the uploaded image is shown back to the user via the 2nd ajax call keep displaying the loading image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing. Keep the loading image in an img tag as like the following

```
<img id="load" src="../image/ajax-loader.gif"/>
```

Now load it into where you want to display

```
$("#loading_image").html($("#load").html());
```